# Output of folders inside which there is a desired file

Tags: java, android, file, listview

In my program, the following are implemented there is a `listView` in it, I bring out the folders that have certain data in the inside. But some of them are empty. I'm trying to make a check that it does not display empty folders for me in the `listView`

```
public static File dir= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/Sales/Archive");

ArrayList<String> theNamesOfFiles = new ArrayList<>();
        File[] filelist = dir.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < filelist.length; i++) {
            long diff = (new Date().getTime() - filelist[i].lastModified())  / 144 / 144 / 144;
            Arrays.sort(filelist, Comparator.comparingLong(File::lastModified).reversed());
            if (diff < 72)
                theNamesOfFiles.add(filelist[i].getName());
        }
```

After some attempts, it turned out that he goes into every file there looking for what I need. But he displays everything the same without them

```
File Path = new File((new File(ArchiveDir)).getParent());
        File[] listFile = Path.listFiles();
        for (File file : listFile) {
            File[] listFile2 = file.listFiles();
            for (File file2 : listFile2){
                if (file.isDirectory() && file2.getName().toUpperCase().contains("S")) {
                    File[] filelist = Path.listFiles();
                    for (int i = 0; i < filelist.length; i++) {
                        long diff = (new Date().getTime() - filelist[i].lastModified()) / 144 / 144 / 144;
                        Arrays.sort(filelist, Comparator.comparingLong(File::lastModified).reversed());
                        if (diff < 72)
                            theNamesOfFiles.add(filelist[i].getName());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I can't understand the question properly.

Comment: @Anirudhdhsinh Jadeja Changed the question. I hope it's better this way

Comment: As I can understand, You are storing the names of the files in `theNamesOfFiles`. So, if we run `theNamesOfFiles.get(index)` it will give us the individual file names right?

Comment: @Anirudhdhsinh Jadeja I may not have tested

Comment: if my answer doesn't help, let me know in comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution to my problem. But there is a tiny nuance in it. My program creates a file every time it starts (data backup) and for some reason this code only skips the created file.

```
int i = 0;

File Path = new File((new File(ArchiveDir)).getParent());
        File[] listFile = Path.listFiles();
        for (File file : listFile) {
            i ++;
            File[] listFile2 = file.listFiles();
            for (File file2 : listFile2){
                if (file2.getName().toUpperCase().contains("S")) {
                    long diff = (new Date().getTime() - listFile[i].lastModified()) / 144 / 144 / 144;
                    Arrays.sort(listFile, Comparator.comparingLong(File::lastModified).reversed());
                    if (diff < 72) {
                        theNamesOfFiles.add(listFile[i].getName());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand,`theNamesOfFiles` is a list of folders. And it contains individual folder's names. So, if you want to check if that folder is empty or not it can be done by `file.length()` function. Which returns `0` if the `file` is empty.

Here's the solution that I think will work best for you.

```
 if (file.isDirectory() && file2.getName().toUpperCase().contains("S")) {
                    File[] filelist = file2.listFiles(); //update
                    for (int i = 0; i < filelist.length; i++) {
                        long diff = (new Date().getTime() - filelist[i].lastModified()) / 144 / 144 / 144;
                        Arrays.sort(filelist, Comparator.comparingLong(File::lastModified).reversed());
                        if (diff < 72)
                          if(filelist[i].length() !=0) //update
                            theNamesOfFiles.add(filelist[i].getName());//update
                    }
                }
```

This will ensure that the element present at the index `i` is not empty. And if it is empty it will be skipped. I won't be added to your list.

Comment: Nothing changed

Comment: Try replacing the if condition with `listFile2[i].length()!=0`.

Comment: `listFile2 [i] .length () 1 = 0` it will give an error if you write it this way.

Comment: My bad... It was `!` instead of `1`

Comment: I didn't mean a typo, but this `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3`

Comment: I think, I won't be able to answer properly. I am voting it.

Comment: I tried one more time. Can you try my updated ans?

Comment: Everything is still (

Comment: try replacing `file2.listfiles` with `file.listfiles`

Comment: Everything is still